# Convert clickable anchor tags to plain text in html document

Tags: php, html, replace, anchor, domdocument

I am trying to match `<a>` tags within my content and replace them with the link text followed by the url in square brackets for a print-version.

The following example works if there is only the "href".  If the `<a>` contains another attribute, it matches too much and doesn't return the desired result.

How can I match the URL and the link text and that's it?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$content = '<a href="http://www.website.com">This is a text link</a>';
$result = preg_replace('/<a href="(http:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\\.:\/]{1,})">([\\s\\S]*?)<\/a>/',
     '<strong>\\2</strong> [\\1]', $content);
echo $result;
?>
```

Desired result:

```
<strong>This is a text link </strong> [http://www.website.com]
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back. Yes I was able to use the "?" for the ungreedy match to get the desired result.  This works well for this particular situation. However, I do like your method of parsing the DOM.  I need to play around with that some more to understand it fully.

Comment: Using regex to parse valid html is an inappropriate and untrustworthy tool because regex is "DOM-ignorant". IOW, regex doesn't know if it is matching tags or just text that resembles tags.  The professional/reliable way to to manipulate an html document is with a legitmiate DOM parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the match ungreedy using `?`.
You should also take into account there may be attributes before the `href` attribute.

```
$result = preg_replace('/<a [^>]*?href="(http:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\\.:\/]+?)">([\\s\\S]*?)<\/a>/',
    '<strong>\\2</strong> [\\1]', $content);
```

Answer (score 9):

You should be using DOM to parse HTML, not regular expressions...

Edit: Updated code to do simple regex    parsing on the href attribute value.

Edit #2: Made the loop regressive so     it can handle multiple replacements.

```
$content = '
<p><a href="http://www.website.com">This is a text link</a></p>
<a href="http://sitename.com/#foo">bah</a>

<a href="#foo">I wont change</a>

';


 $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content);

    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    $len = $anchors->length;

    if ( $len > 0 ) {
        $i = $len-1;
        while ( $i > -1 ) {
        $anchor = $anchors->item( $i );

        if ( $anchor->hasAttribute('href') ) {
            $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
            $regex = '/^http/';

            if ( !preg_match ( $regex, $href ) ) { 
            $i--;
            continue;
            }

            $text = $anchor->nodeValue;
            $textNode = $dom->createTextNode( $text );

            $strong = $dom->createElement('strong');
            $strong->appendChild( $textNode );

            $anchor->parentNode->replaceChild( $strong, $anchor );
        }
        $i--;
        }
    }

    echo $dom->saveHTML();
    ?>
```

Comment: `/^http/` can be determined without the overhead of regex -- `strpos() === 0`.  I used this page to close 5 other pages today, so it would be great if you could tune this answer up to represent your best, current advice.