# PHP - Extracting text from HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a long string of HTML that contains

```
<p>
<img>
<span>
```

and a bunch of other tags.

Is there anyway of extracting ONLY the text within the tags from this string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to extract all text within any tags, the simple way is to strip the tags: [**strip_tags()**](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)

If you want to remove specific tags, maybe [**this SO questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439751/anchor-tags-to-plain-text-within-content) helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'll be getting a lot of bashing for this, but for a simple task like this I'd use regular expressions.

```
preg_match_all('~(<span>(.*?)</span>)~', $html, $matches);
```

`$matches[0]` will contain all the span tags and their contents, `$matches[1]` contains only the contents.

For more complicated stuff you might want to take a look at [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or similar:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = str_get_html($html);

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
   echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
```

Etc.